# Not able to setup DDNS in the wireless router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn, ddns

I recently bought ASUS RT-AC51U. So, I tried to setup DDNS in the router to create a VPN. But when I tried to setup DDNS, it is showing this error:

> "The wireless router currently uses a private WAN IP address
>   (192.168.x.x, 10,x,x,x, or 172.16.x.x).. This router may be in the
>   multiple-NAT environment and DDNS service cannot work in this
>   environment."

I am using a local static address for internet connection which was provided by the local ISP. As I can understand from the error message that the ISP already uses a router/modem which has uses NAT.

So what could be the solution to setup DDNS in my router? Also I don't have access to ISP router/modem.

Comment: In order to have DDNS working, your router must have a public IP address... You cannot do it without it. You need to contact the ISP and find out first if it's possible on your plan because many residential plans sit behind an Carrier grade NAT, which means you will never get a public IP without upgrading to a business package. If it is possible, you need to find out how to put your modem in bridge mode so it passes the public IP through to your router.

Comment: They don't provide me a dedicated modem. I only have the wire coming into my house, which I put it directly into my own router. May be they are using carrier grade NAT. They told me that they can provide a public static IP address for 1 year. But it will cost some money.

Comment: Without a public IP address, either static or dynamic, you will not get DDNS to work.

Comment: Then I think I have to buy the public IP from them

Answer (score 7):

I had the **DOUBLE NAT** problem with the **ASUS RT-N56U** connected to a Dlink Modem/Router when i was trying to use the **AIDisk** feature to access my USB hard drive via FTP.
I couldn't use **DDNS** service, the router displayed this message : **"This router may be in the multiple-NAT environment and DDNS service cannot work in this environment.''**

I solved it by using **"Bridge"** type of connection on the Dlink Modem/Router, then setup the ASUS Router on **PPPOE** connection type using the Username & Password provided by ISP.

UPDATE:

To set Bridge connection type on your modem, you'll have to reconfigure your modem, either reset it to default or simply remove the current configuration, during configuration when you are presented with **"type of network protocol"** or **"Connection type"** such as **"pppoe"** , **"ipoe"** ,**"Bridge"**, then select **"Bridge"** and continue to the following steps.
If you don't know how to configure your modem, google the model of the modem you'll find a guide on how to do that. because each device has different interface.

Comment: Could you expand on how the OP should put their device into bridge mode? Please see [answer] and take our [tour].

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Steps to resolution (order matters):

1. Verify that there are **no other NAT service** inside your local
   network.
2. **Verify that modem is on bridge mode** (talk to your infrastructure provider, i.e. cable company).
3. Talk to your ISP, and request them to change the assigned (to your modem) IP address (some ISP's have limited IPv4 IP pools, and they do internal tricks, like adding an additional NAT inside their infrastructure, so that one IP can be furthermore shared, [more info](https://www.reddit.com/r/HomeNetworking/comments/7eaul5/help_in_resolving_double_nat_asus_rtac68u/dq5c4eh?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)). - **This is what resolved the problem in my case!**